# ExtJs Checkbox Bind Issue

Tags: extjs, checkbox

A checkbox in ExtJs Form Panel is not binding properly , i.e when the value is changed from checked(value is 1) to unchecked (value is 0) the value in model for the respective field is still checked(1). This issue occurs in version 6.2.0.981, but the issue is not reproducible in latest version 6.2.1.167. Here is the fiddle for the same, toggle between the versions and check the issue. please let us know if there are any workaround for this issue in 6.2.0.981 version. Also in release notes of 6.2.1.167 its told that "EXTJS-21886 - Checkboxes don't return the correct value" is fixed, but how to have this fix in previous versions?

[CheckBox Bind issue Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1v08)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fix this by adding

```
uncheckedValue: 0
```

to your checkbox config. [Excerpt from the docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.form.field.Checkbox.html#cfg-uncheckedValue):

> By default this is undefined, which results in nothing being submitted for the checkbox field when the form is submitted

The bug was that nothing was submitted during model update as well, and since nothing was provided, the value of the model was not updated.

Answer (score 0):

In ExtJS 6.6 I was still trying to figure this out and it wasn't as straight forward as I'd hoped (Having the checkbox bind to the model and pass 1 for true and 0 for false to the binding). I wanted to avoid having a formula with a middle man binding in the model because I'd have to have a formula for every checkbox and that seemed silly.. Extending the combo box class and overriding `getValue` method like below. The accepted answer worked ok for unchecked but I was still getting `true` on checked.

```
Ext.define('Components.BinaryCheckBox', {
extend: 'Ext.form.field.Checkbox',
xtype: 'binary-checkbox',
getValue: function () {

    if (this.value) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
},
```

});